# How to change the state config of UIButton in iOS back to default

Tags: ios, uibutton

As the title suggests, need to change the state config back to default. How do I do it?

Need some guidance on this. Thanks.

EDIT:

I have a quiz functionality. When a person selects a answer, if correct then the background will be changed to green. Else, it will be red. When he selects another answer, the previous button should get back to default status.

Comment: can you please explain more about your issue?

Comment: in this case you can manage yourself by using button.banckgroundColor.

Comment: the green and red refer to images i have attached...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the button properties by setting their properties

```
myButton.highlighted = YES/NO;
myButton.selected = YES/NO;
myButton.enabled = YES/NO;
```